# "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." error while creating a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am faced with the aformentioned error when I am sending message from background.js (service_worker) to popup.js file. But if I do the opposite it works fine. Please help me resolve this issue. This is my first time doing something related to a Chrome extension.
P.S. I would really appreciate if you code the changes too.

```text
root/ 
  manifest.json
  popup.js
  popup.html
  background.js
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Fetch Tab URLs"
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
  msg: 'something_completed',
  data: {
    subject: 'Loading',
    content: 'Just completed!',
  },
});
```

**popup.js**

```
  if (request.msg === 'something_completed') {
    //  To do something
    console.log(request.data.subject);
    console.log(request.data.content);
  }
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Popup</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="sendMessage">Send Message to Background</button>
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The popup runs scripts only when it's visible, so when it's hidden it can't receive messages.